# adding some text to multiple folders using batch script

Tags: batch-file, version, directory, rename

I have some software folders like these:

CCleaner 3.17
Firefox v.18.0.2
Avant Browser v2013.01.09

as you can see some of them have the "v" and "v." as version indicator and some does not have it.

I am trying to find a way to add "v." before the number in a folder and all of its subfolders using batch file. if it does not have "v" or "v." add "v." and if it has "v" replace it with "v." and in case if it has the "v." do nothing.

I will be grateful if you could please help me in this matter.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit tricky. My solution assumes that the version number is the remaining text after the last space in the existing folder name.

The code below will appropriately rename all folders in the current directory that have at least one space in the name. It does not recurse into sub-folders. The code will break if the version text contains `!` or `=`, though that is unlikely to be a problem.

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
for /d %%F in ("* *") do (
  set "folder=%%F"
  setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
  for %%A in ("!folder: =\!") do (
    for /f "eol=: tokens=* delims=v." %%B in ("%%~nxA") do (
      if "%%~nxA" neq "v.%%~B" ren "!folder!" "!folder:%%~nxA=v.%%~B!"
    )
  )
  endlocal
)
```

If you want to recurse into the sub-folders, then an outer loop is required, and the folders must be sorted in reverse order so that the deepest folders are processed first.

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
for /f "eol=: delims=" %%D in ('dir /s /ad /b * ^| sort /r') do (
  pushd "%%D"
  for /d %%F in ("* *") do (
    set "folder=%%F"
    setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
    for %%A in ("!folder: =\!") do (
      for /f "eol=: tokens=* delims=v." %%B in ("%%~nxA") do (
        if "%%~nxA" neq "v.%%~B" ren "!folder!" "!folder: %%~nxA= v.%%~B!"
      )
    )
    endlocal
  )
  popd
)
```